# Scala: "override protected val" results in error when defining case class constructor

Tags: scala, overriding, protected

I am experiencing some strange thing related with case classes and `override protected val`.

Let's say `trait T` have a protected `def` (or `val`).

```
trait T {
  protected def s: String
  def print(): Unit = println(s)
}
```

I can override this method `def s` with `val s`. There's no problem.

```
class A(override val s: String) extends T
```

OK. It compiles. But this makes `s` public since there is no protected keyword.

```
class B extends T {
  override protected val s: String = "Show me the money"
}
```

OK. It compiles. (`s` of `class B` is protected)

```
class C(override protected val s: String) extends T
```

OK. It compiles. (`s` of `class C` is protected)
Let's do these with `case class`.

```
case class D(override val s: String) extends T
```

OK. It compiles. (although `s` of `class D` is public)

```
case class E() extends T {
  override protected val s: String = "Show me the money"
}
```

OK. It compiles. (`s` of `class E` is protected)

```
case class F(protected val s: String) extends T
```

OK.  It compiles. (`s` of `class F` is protected, and also `s` is overriden as it was not concrete in `trait T`. It was abstract, so `override` keyword is not necessary.)

```
case class G(override protected val s: String) extends T
```

Here, compile error appears.
`error: value s$1 overrides nothing`

Basically, `class F` and `class G` are the same. `class F` overrides `s` and `s` is protected. This can be shown by that `F("Something").print()` will indeed print `Something`.
`override protected val` can be used in case class as `class E` shows. It did not make errors in defining normal class `C`.

However, only defining `class G` results in a compile error.

Why does this thing happen?

I'm using Scala 2.10.3

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Please report it [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/).

Comment: @sschaef OK. I'll report.

Comment: definietly a bug. Because `s` is protected, scala generates a separate syntetic `<caseaccessor> def s$1` public method that returns `s` so that companion object of `G` can have access to it, for example. Both are marked `override` even though `s$1` overrides nothing.

Comment: also, a protected val parameter for a case class isn't really of any use: you can get the val's value without being a subclass using the extractor. So `s` might just as well be public.

Comment: Submitted: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8132

Comment: Although it isn't of any use, I think that the compiler error should not be like now, as the comparison between `case class F` and `case class G` shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug will be fixed in `Scala 2.11.0-M8`

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8132